# Why is Drupal not sending mail?

Tags: emails, 9

When submitting a contact form there is no mail sent, eventhough there is a confirmation message. Or when trying to send a password reset link, everything goes well, Drupal says "If MYMAIL@MYDOMAIN.XX is a valid account, an email will be sent with instructions to reset your password." but no mail is sent.

- Sendmail is installed, tested with PHP mail() and working fine.
- Tested Sendmail through the command line and working fine: `echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v MYMAIL@MYDOMAIN.XX`
- Testing via drush also works fine with: `drush php-eval "print mail('MYMAIL@MYDOMAIN.XX','Test subject from drush','Test message','From: drush@MYSERVER');"`
- Installed helper module that outputs in watchdog 'sent' message, but no mail is sent
- When submitting forms in Drupal there are no entries in mail.log or syslog

**Edit 1**: this is a live server. There is no Mail Safety module installed. I would like to use the existing Sendmail as it is used succesfully on my other servers with Drupal sites.

**Edit 2**: Some other Drupal sites on the same server are succesfully sending mail, no idea why and why this one is not...

**Edit 3**: The Drupal sites that are not sending mail are test sites TEST.DOMAIN.XX
The sites that DO send mail are the normal ones, WWW.DOMAIN.XX

**Why is Drupal not sending mail and how could I debug this problem further? Thanks**

Comment: Live server? Or locally? Maybe Mailhog? Maybe Mail Safety module installed? Swiftmailer? SMTP?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I made an edit in the question. A last resort would be using an external SMTP but seems unreasonable because there's a working one on the server

Comment: Sounds like someone clever prevents mails from test site being sent, maybe on server-level?!

Comment: That would be a possible scenario yes. However I'm the one to maintain the server and didn't do such a thing...

Comment: We don't know if you have other mail plugins installed, by default it's only core/lib/Drupal/Core/Mail/Plugin/Mail/PhpMail.php. There you'll find the PHP mail() command. You might want to start debugging here. First remove the @ from @mail() to see error messages.

Comment: This is going to be impossible to debug on our end. Start with the above. Are appropriate MX/TXT/SPF records in place, etc

Comment: I've got no mail modules installed and tried with the @ removed, there are no error messages. All appropriate records are in place and other mail from php is coming through. I understand this is hard to debug and letting this rest now, the problem persists only on the test site so that's nice.

Comment: Thanks leymannx and Kevin, if and when a solution arrives, I will update.